# Can you prevent LinqDataSource from setting a property?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

I've got a Linq 2 SQL object I'm trying to update.  Two of the properties on this object are related to each other, and setting one sets the other.

So if I do:

Foo.Code = BEER;

The Foo.CodeID property will automatically be set to 5 (or whatever.)

The problem is that LinqDataSource sets Foo.Code, then immediately sets Foo.CodeID... which is not bound to anything since we want the users to set just Code.  This  immediately sets them both back to null.

I know I can use Parameters to default values, but is there any way to just tell LinqDataSource to not even set a property?

EDIT:  Worked around issue by creating a hidden field, and assigning the correct value to that in the formview's ItemUpdating event.  Would still like to avoid doing the same lookup four times though...

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to make the Code property private (select the Code property in the dbml and set the access property in the Properties window) and create a new public property over which you have more control?

I personally have have written a generator that generates the necessary files for me (like sqlmetal), giving me full control over the code. Perhaps this is an option for you as well, if you do not like the generated dbml.